# How to do Exact match in FT search in xpages

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I used exact match search in in xpage view panel(Version 8.5.2). But I could not get it to work. I used the following code `Field EmpName="Kumar"`. When I search Kumar, The ft search returning Empname contains "Kumar Vijay".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way FT indexing and search work. The word you searched for is found in the item and that's why it is returned. You'll need to use for example the `keys` property in View Panel for exact match.

Comment: Please check the answers for the five questions you have asked and accept the correct ones.

Comment: Panu. I dont know about seleting answers option before . Thanks for the help.